# Simplification of this algebraic expression

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I have an expression like this:

$$\sum _n A_n e^{i a k_n} \alpha ^{\frac{E-k_n}{\omega }} \left(\frac{\alpha  g}{2}+\frac{g \left(E-k_n\right)}{2 \alpha  \omega }+i\right)+\sum _m B_m e^{i a q_m} \alpha ^{\frac{E-q_m}{\omega }} \left(\frac{\alpha  g}{2}+\frac{g \left(E-q_m\right)}{2 \alpha  \omega }-i\right)=0$$

from which I need to obtain $\displaystyle D_{mn}=\frac{B_m}{A_n}$.

I was thinking I could abstract the relation between these coefficients by using the orthogonality of these phases $e^{i\alpha k}$ but $\alpha$ also has an exponent which depends on $k$ and another term also depends on $k$. Are there any ways to find $D_{mn}$ from this expression?

---

Edit: This expression is obtained in a quantum mechanics problem where these $As$ and $Bs$ are the amplitudes of the wavefunction and the quantity $D_{mn}$ is called $S$-matrix.

---

So my initial thought was to multiply the equation by $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-i a\mu_n}$ and integrate from it over $ak_n$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ such that the Kronecker delta collapses the sum but I have different sum on two terms so I am not sure if that is the way to go.